# About a mixture

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, gaussian

Consider the following mixture model for a univariate density function
$$
(1) \quad f(x)=\int_{(m, \sigma^2)\in D} g(x; m, \sigma^2) \mu(d(m, \sigma^2))
$$
where $D$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+$, $(m, \sigma^2)$ denotes the pair of mean  and variance, $g(\cdot; m, \sigma^2)$ is the univariate Normal density function
with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$, $\mu$ is a probability measure over $D$.

I'm interested in understanding which classes of density functions can (or cannot) be "approximated" as in (1).

That is, can we characterise the class, $\mathcal{F}$, of densities, $f(\cdot)$, for which there exists $D,\mu$ such that the "distance" between $f(\cdot)$ and $\int_{(m, \sigma^2)\in D} g(x; m, \sigma^2) \mu(d(m, \sigma^2))$ is small?

I found in various papers/books  sentences along the lines of "There is an obvious sense in which the mixture of normals approach, given enough components, can approximate any density" (see [here](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s10259.pdf) for instance).
I also found some papers proposing formalisation of this sentence within the finite mixture case. See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27589/mixtures-of-gaussian-distributions-dense-in-distributions) for a related question. However, I could not find anything formally dealing with the infinite mixture case as (1).

Would you have some references to suggest? If I set $D$ very large, wouldn't (1) encompass a quite general class of densities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\si{\sigma}\newcommand\ep{\varepsilon}\newcommand\de{\delta}$Any probability distribution on $\R$ can be approximated by a discrete probability distribution on $\R$. Any discrete probability distribution on $\R$ is a mixture of Dirac probability distributions on $\R$. The Dirac probability distribution supported at a point $a\in\R$ can be approximated by the normal distribution with a small variance centered at $a$.

Thus indeed, if the set $D$ is large enough, then any probability distribution on $\R$ can be approximated by a mixture of normal distributions $N(m,\sigma^2)$ with $(m,\si^2)\in D$.

---

Another way: any probability distribution $\nu$ on $\R$ can be approximated by the convolution $\nu*N(0,\si^2)$ of $\nu$ with the centered normal distribution $N(0,\si^2)$ with a small variance $\si^2$, and such a convolution is a mixture of normal distributions:
\begin{equation*}
    \nu*N(0,\si^2)=\int_\R N(y,\si^2)\nu(dy). \tag{0}
\end{equation*}
If now the set $D$ is large enough to, say, contain a set of the form $C_\de\times(0,\ep)$, where $\ep\in(0,\infty)$, $\de$ is a small positive number, and the set $C_\de\subseteq\R$ is such that $\nu(C_\de)>1-\de$, then for small $\si^2\in(0,\ep)$
\begin{equation*}
    \nu\approx\nu*N(0,\si^2)\approx\int_{C_\de} N(y,\si^2)\nu(dy)
=\int_D N(y,s^2)\mu(dy\times d(s^2)), \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $\mu(dy\times d(s^2)):=\nu(dy)1(y\in C_\de,s^2=\si^2)$ --
so that $\nu$ will be approximated by the mixture $\int_D N(y,s^2)\mu(dy\times d(s^2))$ of normal distributions $N(m,s^2)$ with $(m,s^2)\in D$.

**Details:** The approximate equalities in (1) can be understood as follows. Suppose that $\si_n^2\downarrow0$ and $\de_n\downarrow0$ (as $n\to\infty$). Then, by [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem), $\nu*N(0,\si_n^2)\to\nu$ weakly; that is, for any bounded continuous function $g\colon\R\to\R$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    (\nu*N(0,\si_n^2))(g)\to\nu(g), 
\end{equation*}
where $\nu(g):=\int_\R g\,d\nu$; this is how the first approximate equality in (1) can be understood.

Next, by (0), for any bounded continuous function $g\colon\R\to\R$ with $M:=\sup_{x\in\R}|g(x)|<\infty$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &\Big|(\nu*N(0,\si_n^2))(g)-\int_{C_{\de_n}} N(y,\si_n^2)(g)\nu(dy)\Big| \\ 
    =&\Big|\int_{\R} N(y,\si_n^2)(g)\nu(dy)-\int_{C_{\de_n}} N(y,\si_n^2)(g)\nu(dy)\Big| \\ 
    \le&\int_{\R\setminus C_{\de_n}} N(y,\si^2)(|g|)\nu(dy) \\ 
    \le& M\nu(\R\setminus C_{\de_n})\le M\de_n\to0; 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
this is how the second approximate equality in (1) can be understood.

So, for any bounded continuous function $g\colon\R\to\R$,
\begin{equation*}
    \Big(\int_{C_{\de_n}} N(y,\si_n^2)\nu(dy)\Big)(g)
=\int_{C_{\de_n}} N(y,\si_n^2)(g)\nu(dy)\to\nu(g). 
\end{equation*}
That is, we have the weak convergence of the normal mixtures $\int_{C_{\de_n}} N(y,\si_n^2)\nu(dy)$ to $\nu$. (The equality in the latter display is an instance of the Fubini theorem.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer: my notation contained typos because I was denoting both the probability measure over $D$ and the mean of a normal by $\mu$. Now I'm using $\mu$ for the probability measure and $m$ for the mean. Could you rephrase the notation of your answer accordingly? I'm very sorry for this but I cannot follow from "Another way [...]"

Comment: @TEX : Done ( I too, did not notice that $\mu$ was used to denote two different things).

Comment: Thanks. I think, I'm confused about the following step. In the part "Another way [...]", it seems that you fix $\sigma^2$ and approximate $\nu$ as an integral on $C_{\delta}\subset \mathbb{R}$. Instead, in (1), $D$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+$. How should I think about this "dimension reduction"? Why aren't we integrating also wrto the variance?

Comment: Also, there seems to be a sense that distribution with fat tails cannot be approximated by Gaussian mixtures. Does this show up in your arguments and if yes where?

Comment: @TEX : (i) The dimension reduction should only be welcome. Anyway, the mixture can be rewritten as an integral over entire $D$ (as is now shown), with zero weights of some/most mixture components. You can say we do integrate over the variance values, but w.r. to the Dirac measure on $(0,\infty)$ supported just at one point $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have references for your arguments? For example, is this "any probability distribution $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ can be approximated by the convolution $\nu*N(0,\sigma^2)$ of $\nu$ with the centered normal distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$ with a small variance $\sigma^2$, and such a convolution is a mixture of normal distributions" a Theorem that I can cite?

Comment: @TEX : (ii) Of course, since $D$ is compact, the tails of any mixture of the normal distributions $N(m,s^2)$ with $(m,s^2)\in D$ will be light, normal-like in the far-away tail zones close enough to $\pm\infty$ and hence usually not **relatively** close to the corresponding far-away tails of the approximated distribution $\nu$. But as far as the absolute (not relative) approximation error is concerned, the far-away tail probabilities for $\nu$ will be small and thus close to the corresponding tail probabilities for the approximating mixture, if $D$ is large enough.

Comment: Thanks. The distinction that you make between relative and absolute approximation error is interesting and makes me thinking how should I formalise the symbol $\approx$ in your answer? Does it stay for "$\int_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|\nu(x)-\nu^{\text{approx}}(x)|dx$ is very small"?

Comment: @TEX : "any probability distribution $\nu$ on $\mathbb R$ can be approximated by the convolution $\nu*N(0,\sigma^2)$ of $\nu$ with the centered normal distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$ with a small variance $\sigma^2$" -- This follows e.g. by Slutsky's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem . The other facts used in this answer are similarly very basic.

Comment: @TEX : "how should I formalise the symbol ≈ in your answer?" -- In the sense of the convergence in distribution. Recall that in your post you did not specify "approximated".

Comment: @TEX : "I don't see how that follows from Slutsky's Theorem" -- This follows because the **convolution** of distributions is the distribution of the **sum** of the corresponding independent random variables.

Comment: Thanks. "In the sense of the convergence in distribution": could you help me to formalise this? When I think of convergence in distribution, I have in mind a countable sequence of distributions. Where is this sequence here?

Comment: @TEX : It certainly does not have to be a sequence. However, you **can** take sequences of values of $\sigma_n^2$ and $\delta_n$ converging to $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the convergence in distribution result. If you could formalise it a bit more in the answer, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: @TEX : I have added details on that.

Comment: I was re-reading your answer and I'm not sure I fully understand some of the notation. In particular, what does it mean $\nu*\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)(g)$ and $\int_{[...]}\mathcal{N}(y,\sigma^2)(g)\nu(dy)$? In particular, I'm confused about the "$(g)$" bit. Does it stand for a product of a PDF with a function?

Comment: Also, why do you need to introduce the function $g$? I'm considering this definition of Slutsky's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem and this definition of weak convergence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution

Comment: Finally, in the second to last inequality you have $\sigma^2$ but I think it should be $\sigma^2_n$.

Comment: @TEX : $\nu(g)$ was defined as $\int_{\mathbb R} g\,d\nu$. So, $(\nu*N(0,\sigma_n^2))(g)=\int_{\mathbb R} g\,d\nu_n$, where $\nu_n:=\nu*N(0,\sigma_n^2)$. Similarly, $\int_B N(y,\sigma_n^2)(g)\nu(dy)$ means $\int_B \big(\int_{\mathbb R} g\,dN(y,\sigma_n^2)\big)\nu(dy)$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: to a r.v. $Y$, this is equivalent to the convergence $Eg(Y_n)\to Eg(Y)$ for all bounded continuous functions $g\colon{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ -- see e.g. the second listed statement in this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties. Also, $Eg(Y_n)\to Eg(Y)$ if and only if $\mu_{Y_n}(g)\to\mu_Y(g)$, where $\mu_{Y_n}$ is the distribution of $Y_n$ and $\mu_Y$ is the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: @TEX : The typo with $\sigma^2$ in place of $\sigma_n^2$ is now fixed.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. But, I'm still unsure on how can I conclude form the last integral the second approximation that you suggest. I think you are using the "if and only if" relation you mention in the above comment but I don't see exactly how.

Comment: @TEX : I am not quite sure what the difficulty you talk about in the your latter comment is, but I have added another detail at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. In the formal arguments that you make, should $C_{\delta_n}$ be compact and where does the compactness play a role?

Comment: @TEX : Your assumption that  "$D$ [is] very large" is interpreted in the answer as follows: "If now the set $D$ is large enough to, say, contain a set of the form $C_\de\times(0,\ep)$". So, if $D$ is compact, then the closure of $C_\de$ will be compact.

Comment: I mean in the formal limit derivation you have the sequence $\{C_{\delta_n}\}_n$. Should each element of this sequence be compact? If yes, where do you use it in the limit derivation?

Comment: @TEX : What I said about $C_\delta$ of course pertains to all $C_{\delta_n}$'s.

Comment: @TEX : Our discussion is now much longer than a usual one on MathOverflow. So, I'd suggest the following. If something in the answer is still unclear, take some time to try to understand it. After that, you may want to ask a corresponding well-stated question -- on Mathematics Stack Exchange, rather than on MathOverflow. Also, I think it would be a good idea to take standard courses in probability and other mathematical subjects related to your research (if you have not done so already).